# I'm studying recursion functions in C for the very first time. I tried to debug the function below and it's all clear except the index grow of n

Tags: c, recursion

```c
int minimum(int *p,int n){

    if (n==1)
        return *(p+0);
    int m = minimum(p,n-1);
    if (m<*(p+(n-1)))
            return m;
    return *(p+(n-1));

}
```

The function checks all the values of an array and it returns the lowest value. 
for example A[n]={1,2,3,4,5} it returns 1

considering n = 5 for example during the execution n goes from 5 to 1 until it goes into the first if ( if (n==1) ) and it returns the value of the first cell of the array p . After the first recall of the function the function itself keeps going ofc and it goes to the next if -->   if (m<*(p+(n-1)))

Alright if i now check the  n value it is 2 and then 3 and 4 and 5 so it reaches the end of the array controllying if there's a value lower than the previous one.

I do understand why n goes from 5 to 1 , but how does it goes from 1 to 5?? How the value of n grows if there's no increase ? i tested the function with a random array and it works completely fine .

*Updated* What i understood by your answers is this :

Ok so basically it's not 1 function at work but 5 (ideally tho) and everytime the cycle returns something it's like one of the function can stop working and focus on the new function with the new value (returning the value in base of the code) . So basically when n is equal 1 the function returns  *(p+0). Once the cycle of the function with n=1 ends with the return , the cycle-function with n=2 starts working with the new value and so on . Is that right?

Comment: when does it increment? it just never change its value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `n` variable never change because each function call has its ows `n`... you are seeing a 'increasing of `n`' because you have to remember that a function call also do a rollback from the last, where n==1, to the first, where n==5, so if you print n after the recursive call, you will see 1->2->3->4->5 just because the function are doing a rollback of the recursive calls

Comment: Ok so basically it's not 1 function at work but 5 (ideally tho) and everytime the cycle returns something it's like one of the function can stop working and focus on the new function with the new value (returning the value in base of the code) . So basically when n is equal 1 the function returns  *(p+0). Once the cycle of the function with n=1 ends with the return , the cycle-function with n=2 starts working with the new value and so on . Is that right?

Comment: yes, start the first one (with n=2) , does what it has to do, arrives to the recursive call,  which will be managed as a normal function call, so it stops, starts the function called by the recursive call (with n=1 ), which it's stopped immediatly because the first if condition is true, so it returns the int, and then the other function call  (with n=2) that has called this one that as just return, 'restarts'. if you have more than 2 calls, the the reasoning is the same, but the first part is repeated many time and then the last also is repated many times

Answer (score 1):

Each recursive function call has *its own* `n`. The calling level's `n` isn't affected by the changes made at the lower recursive calls. So when the lower call returns, the caller's `n` is unmodified.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up multiple different `n` variables. Variable `n == 5` still exists when variable `n == 4` is created, and ceases to exist after `n == 4` is destroyed.

As with every function call, the variables for the called function are created on entry and deleted on return. So, each time the recursive function is invoked, all its local variables are created again for that invocation. They are not shared between different invocations just because the function happens to be the same.

For a variable to be shared between all the invocations of a function call, it must be `static`, but function arguments like `n` can not be `static`.

Answer (score 0):

Every time a function is called, a part of the computer's memory (RAM) is reserved for *the instance* of the called function. The part of the memory is called a *stack* and the portion reserved for the function instance is called a *stack frame*.

Instance-specific data (like function parameters and variables) are stored in the stack frame.

When another function is called (or even the same function again), a new stack frame is created and the new function instance stores its data there. When it returns, the original function instance resumes execution *(note that there is more code after the `int m = minimum(p,n-1);` line, which needs to get executed at some point)* in its own stack frame, retaining the values of the parameters and variables.